# Uninstalling VMware horizon client issue

Tags: permissions, vmware

I'm having trouble uninstalling VMware Horizon Client since it stopped working with the new ubuntu update I got a few days ago.
I tried this

```
sudo env VMWARE_KEEP_CONFIG=yes \
./VMware-Horizon-Client-2006-8.0.0-16522670.x64.bundle -u vmware-horizon-client
bash: ./VMware-Horizon-Client-2006-8.0.0-16522670.x64.bundle: Permission denied
```

but as you can see I get Permission denied even when I used sudo.
any ideas on how to uninstall it?
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either the executable doesn't have the "execute bit" set (fix with `chmod +x VMware-Horizon-Client-2006-8.0.0-16522670.x64.bundle`) or the partition it's on is mounted with `noexec` (check with `mount`).

Comment: thanks, it was the first I execute chmod and it worked